# php foreach display limit and after it display the rest until the limit again

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I want to show 16 data from database per page and foreach 8 of them display

```
<div>There are 8 Data </div>
```

after showing the rest 8 to display again

```
<div>There are 16 Data </div>
```

something like that if possible of course

I tried to use the break after showing 8 data and trying to continue again but without success

the code I tried:

```
$sn_count = 1;
  $html = '';
  $display_datadiv_every = 8;
  foreach($result as $point){
      $html .= "<div class=\"name\">".$sn_count."</div>"
          . "<div class=\"pointsurname\">"
          . $point['name']
          . "</div>";
      if($sn_count++ % $display_datadiv_every == 0)
      {
    echo '<div class="card d-flex mt-2 mb-4" style="width: auto;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 110px;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">There are".$sn_count." data</h5>
      </div>
       </div>';
     }
       } echo $html; 
         }}
```

and it displays me like this:

```
<h5 class="card-title">There are".$sn_count." data</h5>
<h5 class="card-title">There are".$sn_count." data</h5>
foreach 8 data displayed one div and 

        $point['name']  16 times
        $point['name']
```

Comment: Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Post your code. Post your expectation. Post your result.

Comment: i tried to display the code but it got removed for some reason that's why it displayed like this

Comment: Instead of foreach why not use a normal for loop twice?  The 1st loop prints the first 8 records and the 2nd loop prints the last 8 records.  You will need to rethink the logic a little.

Comment: @CharlesEF I did but I want to use the same logic for other pages of pagination, with this logic you suggested i would need to go in every page and do the same

Comment: Wrong opening and closing quotes

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Also, why is this question tagged with MySQL, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: @Nico Haase Why would I want an answer without having MySQL or any database involved ?

Comment: If the problem is really related to any database, share more details. But I would assume that reading the data from the database works already? This makes your problem independent from the database

Answer (score 1):

First define a counter variable outside the loop.
Then put a condition inside the loop that it should show the first 8 result in the first8 div and show rest result in else condition of second div.
Then counter++ inside loop

```
 <?php  
 $counter = 0;   
 foreach($result as $point){
 if($counter < 8){  
  ?>
 <div class="first8"><?php echo $point; ?></div>
 <?php } else { ?>
  <div class="second8"><?php echo $point; ?></div>
  <?php }  ?>

 <?php  $counter++; 
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it